# sql c# check for database updates without while/for loops?

Tags: c#, sql, loops, insert

I have a simple C# program that checks the database for updates every minute via a timed loop. It works fine, but I think its not efficient. Is there a better way to do this?

Thank

Comment: You will have to provide much more detail...

Comment: Why do you think it is not efficient?

Comment: Its not efficient because I have to keep opening/closing a connection every minute to check for database update/inserts, and although it runs about 15mb in memory, the cpu usage is high.

Comment: @user719825: You could always keep the connection open IF that is indeed the bottleneck (which I highly doubt).

Comment: Is this a WinForms app? If so, how many concurrent workstations are running it?  Is your server running short on connections?  There is no absolute obligation to close the connection immediately after your DML statement is executed. Whether that "rule" needs to be in play depends on the use-case/scenario. And is CPU consumption high during the "sleep" phase? Are you using a Timer?

Comment: Doesn't it time out by default? In the connection string I have it set to 1000.  Yes I am running a timer, and I have it sleep. CPU usage lowers a bit when it sleeps. It is a winform application. Only one computer runs it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)?

Comment: Won't it work for SQL Server only? What about such things as PostgreSQL, MySQL, Access etc.?

Comment: @Denis: true, I just assumed the question was SQL Server. Microsoft brainwashing obviously taking its effect on me.